# Error Code 1064, Cant figure this out

Tags: mysql, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE 'mydb.nation' (
'natcode' CHAR(3),
'natname' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
'exchange_rate' DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('natcode'));

CREATE TABLE 'mydb.stock' (
'stckcode' CHAR(3),
'stckname' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
'stckprice' DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
'stckqty' DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
'stckdiv' DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
'stckPE' DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
'natcode' CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY('natcode'),
CONSTRAINT 'natcode'
    FOREIGN KEY('natcode')
    REFERENCES'mydb'.'nation'('natcode')
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);


INSERT INTO 'mydb.nation' ('natcode','natname','exchange_rate') VALUES ('AUS','Australia','0.46'),
INSERT INTO 'mydb.nation' ('natcode','natname','exchange_rate') VALUES ('IND','India','0.0228'),
INSERT INTO 'mydb.nation' ('natcode','natname','exchange_rate') VALUES ('UK','United Kingdom','1'),
INSERT INTO 'mydb.nation' ('natcode','natname','exchange_rate') VALUES ('USA','United States','0.67'),
```

Comment: Does MySQL allow separating insert statements by commas??

Comment: Note: It's generally a good idea to include the full test of an error message, as that makes figuring things out much easier.

Comment: I've generally seen object names delimited by backticks ( ` ) in MySQL. If the object name is not supposed to be `mydb.nation`, but two separate objects (`mydb` and `nation`), you may have a problem there.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to respect MySQL syntax, here's something that passes the muster of DB Fiddle  (MySQL 5.7).  See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kMfBNBx9WRe65cwWyRmUMn/0

```
CREATE TABLE nation (
natcode CHAR(3),
natname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
exchange_rate DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (natcode));

CREATE TABLE stock (
stckcode CHAR(3),
stckname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
stckprice DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
stckqty DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
stckdiv DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
stckPE DECIMAL(9,5) NULL,
natcode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(natcode),
CONSTRAINT natcode
    FOREIGN KEY(natcode)
    REFERENCES nation(natcode)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);


INSERT INTO nation (natcode,natname,exchange_rate) VALUES
  ('AUS','Australia','0.46'),
  ('IND','India','0.0228'),
  ('UK','United Kingdom','1'),
  ('USA','United States','0.67');
```

Comment: I've thrown out all quotes, now at least it passes DB Fiddle.